# Sending variables to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now and I can't seem to understand how to come up with a solution to the problem. I am trying to send an images file path along with the current users session id. For some reason I keep getting an error message, stating that the two POST variables are unidentified indexes.Here is the code:

```php
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "Images Upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
    $target= "Images Upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $target1= $_POST[$target];
    $sessionid= $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $sessionid1= $_POST[$sessionid];

    $query= "insert into images (UserID, Image) values('{$target1}','{$sessionid}')";

    if (mysql_query($query)) {
         echo"<script>alert('Upload Successful!')</script>";
    } else {
         echo "this isn't working";
    }           
} else {
    echo "this isn't working";
}
```

Comment: Why did you add `{}`'s to the variables? And your error means that the `$_POST` variables don't exist (weren't sent).

Comment: I found a video on youtube, i've taken them off

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about what the purpose of $_POST is. $_POST variable is filled with submitting a html form. so this line:

```
$target1= $_POST[$target];
```

is trying to find a submitted form input by the name of "Images Upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]. like this:

```
<input type='text' name='Images Upload/example.png' value = 'someValue'>
```

since it doesn't exist it gives an error. and sets your target1 as null.

just remove these lines and it'll presumebly work;

```
$target1= $_POST[$target];
$sessionid1= $_POST[$sessionid];
```

and change this line to:

```
$query= "insert into images (UserID, Image) values('$target','$sessionid')";
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do with :

```
$target1= $_POST[$target];
```

and

```
sessionid1= $_POST[$sessionid];
```

Please read about $_SESSION and $_POST here http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php

try this :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "Images Upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"])){
$target= "Images Upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$sessionid= $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query= "insert into images (UserID, Image) values('$target','$sessionid')";

if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo"<script>alert('Upload Successful!')</script>";
    }
    else{echo "this isn't working";}

} else{echo "this isn't working";}
```

Also you have "space" in directory name "Images Upload", try to avoid these spaces.

I hope you get an idea...